# Why floating hint animation doesn't work?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-animation, android-textinputlayout

I need to animation like this of first:

[image]

(Gif from Internet) But even with `app:hintAnimationEnabled="true"` the animation doesn't work. Always the second example of gif. What could be the problem? What am I doing wrong?

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Login"
    app:hintEnabled="true"
    app:hintAnimationEnabled="true">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the hint for TextInputLayout as well for animations to work, I've only tried setting hint dynamically which works as expected, try setting the hint in xml first to see if it works, if it does not then do it dynamically:

```
TextInputLayout inputLayout = findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);
inoutLayout.setHint("Hint");
```

Comment: I tried both. Set hint for `TextInputLayout` and by code `setHint()`. Both didn't work.

Comment: Yes, one delete, two try